# Changing model in face-recognition and face-registration

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, face-recognition

I have a python project about face-recognition, actually i am using it from [Here](https://github.com/SamSamhuns/face_registration_and_recognition_milvus), but the main problem is that author uses "**facenet-trtserver**" and "**face-reidentification-retail-0095**" models for detecting(you can see it in **app_docker_compose/app/models/model.py** ). But accuracy of this models is too low(according to my research), so i want to use yolo or another pre-trained model i used in another example.

But i am not sure that yolo or my model are capable to be used for this project, maybe someone can look and give me advices.

Additional information:

- I have no information how author trained his models.
- Here is link for models used in another projects: [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Nd_rDs3BC64rsRyZrIgWj0zEKBD904v1?usp=sharing).

Comment: have you asked the author?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i do not think he is gonna reply, but last contribution was on august 21th

Comment: you can't just use ***arbitrary*** models for a specific purpose like ***face reidentification***. those arbitrary models weren't trained for that.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i asked the author, he says change the threshold, i changed but it is still not working properly https://github.com/SamSamhuns/face_registration_and_recognition_milvus/issues/4